# Distance matrix time series analysis? (Ecology/diversity)

Tags: time-series, distance, ecology, diversity

I am trying to analyze a time series of ecological data. Each time point in the series is a matrix of animals-by-foods (that they were observed to eat). For each of these time points, I compute the distance between each pair of animals' foods to generate a distance matrix of food dissimilarity between animals in each time point. What I want to investigate is how food-consumption dissimilarity changes through time. For example, how does season influence food-consumption similarity.

It's not clear to me how I would go about doing that. On the one hand, I thought that I could simply take the mean dissimilarity for each time point and regress that against season. However, this seems sub-optimal since it obviously reduces the data greatly. A friend suggested a mixed-model approach where the response is the vector of all pairwise distances with a fixed effect of season and separate random effects for each of the animal IDs associated with each pairwise distance but I haven't found much online backing up the validity of this suggestion. Finally, multivariate approaches don't seem appropriate because my response variable would be several different distance matrices rather than one.

Any and all suggestions welcome!

**Example of raw data** where a-d (rows) represent each animal. Columns represent different food items and their proportional abundance in an animal's diet

```
$Summer_Year1
  food_1     food_2     food_3     food_4    food_5     food_6
a 0.00000000 0.00000000 0.46124791 0.00000000 0.5387521 0.00000000
b 0.00000000 0.45506757 0.12772222 0.02664421 0.3704323 0.02013374
c 0.23193584 0.03589622 0.07236377 0.02344589 0.2364787 0.39987961
d 0.09437105 0.27949426 0.00000000 0.24855345 0.1562197 0.22136156
.
.
.
$Winter_Year2
  food_1    food_2    food_3    food_4
a 0.2634612 0.1876040 0.3021284 0.2468064
b 0.2364633 0.7635367 0.0000000 0.0000000
c 0.2496862 0.2261279 0.2936277 0.2305582
d 0.5786246 0.1852360 0.0000000 0.2361394
```

From these animal-by-food matrices, I computed animal-animal dissimilarities in diet composition (here using Bray-Curtis dissimiliarity with vegan::vegdist in R):

```
$Summer_Year1
      a         b         c
b 0.5018455                    
c 0.6911576 0.6116817          
d 0.8437803 0.5175081 0.4687056
.
.
.
$Winter_Year2
       a          b          c
b 0.57593268                      
c 0.03852387 0.53740882           
d 0.31516336 0.57830069 0.33451958
```

So my aims are to assess how animal-animal diet dissimilarity changes between seasons where I feel like I could:
(1) Average the diet dissimilarity at each time point to reduce each collection period to one measure of diet dissimilarity between all animal species
(2) Use all pairwise values across all distance matrices in my analyses but include some model structure to account for the non-independence of data points
Or, (3) some other approach.

Comment: Hi Matt, a practical example would be very useful. Can you add a sample of your data and examples of the transformations you are applying to it?

Comment: @MichalJ.Figurski thanks for the suggestion! I have updated the post (with hopefully sufficient detail)

Comment: Are the animals the same during the study? so `a` refers always to the same animal?

Answer (score 1):

There's a whole range of statistics for studying how ecological communities of species change across gradients, which use dissimilarity matrices as the response variable. It sounds like you could make use of these to assess your hypotheses.

It sounds like you're already using the R package *vegan* - check out some of the other functions - e.g. *rca*, *cca*, *envfit*, *adonis*.  There are a few nice vignettes available for the package that would be worth reading. It seems to me like your data is equivalent to that used in the examples, but instead of "site" you have "animal", and instead of "species" you have "food".